# Is this sentence grammatically correct and punctuations are used correctly?

Tags: grammaticality, commas, orthography, time

Is this sentence grammatically correct and coherent?

> Based on the availability of my examining committee and committee chair, Tuesday, January 17th, 1 PM - 3PM works for everyone for my candidacy exam.

I do not understand whether putting time information like this ('Tuesday, January 17th, 1 PM - 3PM') is correct or not.

But Grammarly seems to be ok with it.

Comment: A bit unwieldy, perhaps. Otherwise, appears OK. _My_ examining committee?

Comment: You are suggesting to drop "chair"? i.e. `Based on the availability of my examining committee, Tuesday, January 17th, 1 PM - 3 PM works for everyone for my candidacy exam.`

Comment: It's okay but we don't do editing here.

Comment: yeah, I am just trying to understand whats the best way to put time really. Its causing too many commas. What is the best practice for that?

Comment: Please remember that "punctuations" is not an English word, and that you must use inversion in questions.